# DateComponents and Notifications Not Showing

Tags: swift, push-notification, nsdatecomponents

I have made a to do list app. In the app, the user can select 1 of 4 buttons to set a notification. Immediate, morning, afternoon and evening. Currently, the evening and immediate work but the morning and afternoon are not working and I am unsure why.

Here is my code for the evening:

```
@IBAction func eveningTapped(_ sender: Any) {

    eveningEnabled = true
    morningEnabled = false
    lockscreenEnabled = false
    afternoonEnabled = false
}

if eveningEnabled == true {
        var dateComponents = DateComponents()
        dateComponents.hour = 18
        dateComponents.minute = 00
        let trigger = UNCalendarNotificationTrigger(dateMatching: dateComponents, repeats: false)
        let content = UNMutableNotificationContent()
        content.title = taskTextField.text!
        content.body = DescTextField.text!
        content.sound = UNNotificationSound.default()
        content.badge = 1

        let identifier = "UYLLocalNotification"
        let request = UNNotificationRequest(identifier: identifier,
                                            content: content, trigger: trigger)
        center.add(request, withCompletionHandler: { (error) in
            if error != nil {
                // Something went wrong - another alert
            }
        })
    }
```

This works completely fine but the morning doesn't work, here is the code:

```
@IBAction func morningTapped(_ sender: Any) {

    morningEnabled = true
    lockscreenEnabled = false
    afternoonEnabled = false
    eveningEnabled = false
}

if morningEnabled == true {
        var dateComponents = DateComponents()
        dateComponents.hour = 07
        dateComponents.minute = 00
        let trigger = UNCalendarNotificationTrigger(dateMatching: dateComponents, repeats: false)
        let content = UNMutableNotificationContent()
        content.title = taskTextField.text!
        content.body = DescTextField.text!
        content.sound = UNNotificationSound.default()
        content.badge = 1

        let identifier = "UYLLocalNotification"
        let request = UNNotificationRequest(identifier: identifier,
                                            content: content, trigger: trigger)
        center.add(request, withCompletionHandler: { (error) in
            if error != nil {
                // Something went wrong - another alert
            }
        })
    }
```

Comment: Is this your real code? The {} don't match.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your code is absolutely identical (except the DateComponents) in both actions, there should be no difference when running.

But as you have a difference ('morning' is not working) the reason MUST be somewhere else (and not in the code, that you posted here). Maybe your tapAction for morning is not correctly connected in the InterfaceBuilder?

If you would post more code, we could probably better help finding the bug.

First you should check, wether your tapAction is being performed, when you tap. You can do this by adding a log command, like this:

```
print("Morning was tapped")
```

and put this code into your tapAction. Then you should get this log on your log console, after having tapped the corresponding button.

Comment: Okay, so I have checked my connections and when the button is working correctly and all connected up correctly. I am going to test the notification again as my project has been playing up recently. Will keep you updated

Comment: All working now. For some reason the connections were being a bit weird. Thanks for the help

Comment: So it would be nice if you mark my answer as the correct answer!